# Permissions to use redshift COPY command from within lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have a lambda written in .net core. It will invoke a `COPY` command from redshift. My lambda executes under a role which has access to redshift and to s3.

My `COPY` command which looks like this:

`COPY my_table_name FROM 's3://my_bucket/my_file.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=x;aws_secret_access_key=y' DELIMITER ',' CSV;`

This works fine. My problem is that the `CREDENTIALS` I am using for the `COPY` is completely independent of the role which lambda is running under.

Is there a way to execute the `COPY` command using the role which the lambda is executing under?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitely recommend using Role-Based authentication instead of Key-Based, but I believe you will need to assign the role directly to your Redshift cluster instead of trying to pass the role that is assigned to your Lambda function. The `COPY` command runs from within the Redshift cluster, your Lambda function is only telling Redshift to run the command, so it can't really use the Lambda function's role.

Please see the detailed documentation on Redshift [Role-Based authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-access-role-based).